# Prime ideals in $\mathbb{R}[X,Y,Z]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which one of the following ideals is prime?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285047/which-one-of-the-following-ideals-is-prime)

If $T=\mathbb{R}[X,Y,Z]$, then which one is a prime ideal:
A) $\langle X^{2},Y+Z\rangle$
B) $\langle X^{2}YZ,Z\rangle$
C) $\langle XY,XZ+YZ\rangle$
D) $\langle XY,XZ\rangle$.

Comment: You should at least tell us what you have tried doing... All of these examples can be handled with absolutely nothing more than the definition of what  prime ideal is, really!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An ideal $I$ is prime  if $ab \in I$ implies $a \in I$ or $b\in I$ for all $a,b \in R$. Some hints:

D) $XY-XZ = X(Y-Z) \in I$ but neither $X$ nor $Y-Z$ in $I$.

C) $XY \in I$ but neither $X$ nor $Y$ in $I$.

A) Similarly, $X^2$ is in $I$ but $X \notin I$.

B) $\langle X^2 ZY \rangle \subseteq \langle Z \rangle$. Therefore $\langle X^2 YZ, Z \rangle = \langle Z \rangle$. And $\langle Z \rangle$ is prime.

Comment: very thanks goobie

Comment: you are welcome @reme